# Can background bluetooth processes work without app being open? Is there anything that always listens?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I am working on an iOS application that needs to broadcast bluetooth at all times no matter what (as long as bluetooth on the phone is on of course) and i was wondering:

Does an iOS application need to be active in background for Bluetooth peripheral background process to be active?

For example, if the application is not currently opened on the phone's app selector, will the application still work listen?

If not, are there any options for an app to to always be ready to receive a notification or alert (similar to a text message)??

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can specify bluetooth background mode. Refer to the core bluetooth programming guide and the ios application programming guide

Comment: Assuming you mean BTLE...

Comment: I did mean BTLE. So the user does not need the app to be opened whatsoever for it to work?

Comment: Not as long as you use the background modes and implement the appropriate delegate methods. You do have limited background execution time on each delegate invocation - about 3 seconds